# Not able to get a stable deployment using WildFly in docker

Tags: docker, deployment, wildfly, war, apple-m1

I am strangling with my development environment, which is not stable.

I am using Mac M1, Docker, WildFly.

After building the war file successfully, I try to deploy it on WildFly in docker.

Sometimes this line works,

```
docker exec -it example-wildfly.localdev-1 /data/wildfly-15.0.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect 'deploy --force /data/project/packages/backend/target/backend-SNAPSHOT.war'
```

but in most of the cases it stacks or return this error:

> Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available
> at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not
> connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection failed:
> WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The
> connection failed: Connection refused

Looking for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition, but you've given us nothing that we could run and debug.

Comment: This does not sound like a race condition. Can you connect with `docker exec -it /bin/bash`?

Comment: The thing is that the same configuration works normally by my team members!